# How do I get a list from a for expression in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

According to [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html), Terraform `for` expressions can produce either maps or tuples.

However I end up with the following when I try to use the value in a `for_each`:

```
flatten([ for service in var.services: service.subdomains ])
# or
flatten(tolist([ for service in var.services: service.subdomains ]))
# or
tolist(flatten([ for service in var.services: service.subdomains ]))
```

```
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of tuple.
```

---

The value for `services` is as follows:

```
  [
    {
      name = "some-name",
      backend = module.some_module.some_resource,
      subdomains = [
        "subdomainone",
        "subdomaintwo",
      ],
    },
  ]
```

---

[Here is a minimal repro:](https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/0019ac662f5493d107e0d7c8b31ca72d)

```
locals {
  services = [
    {
      name = "some-name",
      subdomains = [
        "subdomainone",
        "subdomaintwo",
      ],
    },
  ]
}

resource local_file "whatever" {

  for_each = setproduct([ "one" ], flatten([ for service in local.services: service.subdomains ]))

  filename = "whatever"
}

output services {
  value = local.services
}

output flatten {
  value = flatten([ for service in local.services: service.subdomains ])
}

output setproduct {
  value = setproduct([ "one" ], flatten([ for service in local.services: service.subdomains ]))
}
```

---

Is there any way in Terraform to convert a tuple to a list?

*(Sidenote: It seems strange that Terraform wouldn't return a list from a for expression instead of a tuple...)*

Comment: As Dan Monego pointed out, for_each only works on sets and maps. So you need to turn this data into a set or map. How do you want this data to be iterated over? That will determine what kind of map or set should be created from it.

Comment: Overall, I'm not particular.  I just want to iterate over each pair of values `[["one","subdomainone",],["one","subdomaintwo",],]`. The problem is I can't seem to [get rid of / convert away from] the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for_each` only works on sets and maps.

It looks `subdomains` is a tuple, so flatten isn't fully flattening your list. I don't know where `var.services` is coming from - it may be possible to make `subdomains` have the type list with a type definition. If not, you could do this:

```
toset(flatten([ for service in var.services: tolist(service.subdomains) ]))
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, ended up with: `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type tuple.`

Comment: Debug it with output statements to find the tuple type, and put a tolist on there. I recommend putting in `output "services" { value = var.services }` and `output "subdomains" { value = <your flatten statement>}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the debug, but I don't know if it shows me what I'm looking for, because Terraform uses the same syntax for tuples as it does lists (`[]`). The output seems inconclusive and doesn't get me any closer to a solution...